# Manage.py utitliy not working properly within Pycharm

Tags: python, django

I happened to change the name of a django's app (just the name of the directory) so everytime I wanted to make the migrations of the models within that app, I couldn't.

After updating every occurence of the string within the project, I run `makemigrations` succesfully within the terminal. But I haven't been successful doing so within Pycharm, apparently it is stuck on the lastest -failed- command, whenever I type `makemigrations app_name` (or any othe command like `shell`) it throws the same message I was seeing prior fixing the error (updating the string):

> ImportError: No module named 'app_name'

Any help?

Comment: Is 'app_name' in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`? Are you in the correct virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, it's on INSTALLED_APPS and I believe I set the Project Interpreter right. It says: virtualenv at "directory/env"

Comment: What I meant for the virtual env, is in the terminal itself, did you run first `workon ...` or `source ...`?

Comment: Yes, I did run `source bin/activate`.

Comment: Have you tried to switch it off and on again :) ? Seriously, did you try to restart PyCharm?

Comment: Yes, I've restarted PyCharm several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is maybe not the best solution to your problem but I had something similar in the past with PyCharm and what I did was to recreate the virtualenv within PyCharm and reinstall all the modules. Make sure that you export your installed modules using the following command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

and then install in the new virtualenv using:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```